# Excel functionality is not working while publishing winform app with clickonce

Tags: winforms, excel, oledb, clickonce

I have published my winforms client application with click once.
I am using visual studio 8 and OS Win Server 2003 SP2.
first using click once i was not able to use excel upload part of my app in windows 7 (64) but it was working on server 2003(32)/2008(64) and windows 8(32bit).
but after some googling I had some suggestions which i have changed.
List of changes I have done

1. changed the OLEDB connection string to `Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source='"`.
2. changed the target platform to X86.
3. removed all the office components from the server and re-installed `AccessDatabaseEngine.exe`.
4. Checked the MIME type all the `.deploy` manifest and all are
       there(also checked the office extensions).

After doing these changes I was able to use the Excel upload on all the OS.

But after 3 versions now its again stopped working.

Now I am out of clues what went wrong.